# How to pop-back NSMenu object?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsmenu, nsmenuitem

As widely known, we can pop up programmatically an NSMenu object by calling -popUpContextMenu:... method.

However, I wonder how to pop the menu object back programmaticaly.

Answer (score 0):

Oops, I found the answer myself:

`- (void)cancelTracking` :Dismisses the menu and ends all menu tracking: